# Image blur effect working on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

I'm testing the blur effect -webkit-filter:blur(5px) which seems to work only with Chrome.

But I've found this:
http://vectorflower.com/preview/trans_banner/

I dont know how they do it, but works with Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know how they do it?

I thought they were "cheating" with 2 images, but the console shows only 1 request per image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css filter specification is pretty new and is not supported yet in IE or Firefox.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

The example you linked to uses the canvas to draw the blur effect directly.